# How to build a unique database model Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I currently have three models: two different users models which support the Devise auth gem : community organizer and regular user, and one community events model.

I'm trying to allow the community organizer to create events :

- To which users can donate funds to ;
- Which users can attend .

I use stripe as the payment gateway. I've setup a controller/model scaffolding for the `Event` model so far :

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
  belongs_to :org_user #organization_user
  has_one :category
end
```

Here is my organization user model :

```
class OrgUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :username, use: :slugged
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
  has_many :events
 end
```

I was told that I may need these particular patterns inside of my events and org_user models

```
   class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    event has_many :attendances
    event has_many :users, through: :attendances
   end

  class OrgUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    org_user has_many :attendances
    org_user has_many :events, through: :attendances
    end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

What is your advice on creating the relationship. I also don't want to forget the User.rb which will sign the form to be a part of the event posted by the :org_user.
 Only the org_user will have the ability to create/post events. Normal Users will have access to the signup form to attend those events. Please, help me clear this hurdle.

Answer (score 2):

Several things :

- The way you right has many through relationship is wrong (see [the doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) )
- You don't model your donation relationship from users to events

You could model things like this :

```
  class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :attendances
    has_many :users, through: :attendances
  end

  class OrgUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :events # as coordinations
  end

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :donations
    has_many :attendances
  end

  class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :event
  end

  class Donation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :event
  end
```

Comment: I will report back to you once I've tried your solution. Thanks for looking into this problem for me.

Comment: Quick question Pak about the attendances model. Should I create a new table to hold it's id (polymorphic) or add it to a current model? What's your advice. Also, which properties would you generate alongside the model in this case :attendances user_id:integer event_id:integer, etc for better description. Add it to your original answer if you can. As soon as I see that the solution is complete. I will mark it as answered.

Comment: Yes, you need to create new tables. It's easier to maintain. Rails associations and migrations already take care of this for you, see the rails guides :)